# Android SQLite onUpgrade add a new table without touching the old ones

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have a database setup in android right now. the database and tables work fine. However, when I want to add a new table and use onUpgrade - the database is created, but doesn't properly work. As in the table looks created but I can't add data to it. when I try the app crashes. All the version 1 tables still look fine.

here is what my onUpgrade looks like:

```
private val newDatabase = listOf<String>(
        "Database1"
    )
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    newDatabase.forEach{
        val table2 = "CREATE TABLE $it ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $AVERAGETIME TEXT DEFAULT \"0\",$DATE TEXT DEFAULT \"0\")"
        db?.execSQL(table2)
    }
}
```

my oncreate looks exactly the same, just uses a different array of strings:

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        originalDatabase.forEach {
            val table1 =
                "CREATE TABLE $it ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $AVERAGETIME TEXT DEFAULT \"0\",$DATE TEXT DEFAULT \"0\")"
            db?.execSQL(table1)
        }

    }
```

Is this the best way to add a new table? once the table is made, it seems to be blank and not work right. even though I have default values set to it.

I tried looking through other posts but can't seem to find one concrete answer

Comment: What does "doesn't properly work" mean to you? Note that default values for columns does not mean any rows are inserted.

Comment: @laalto As in, the table looks created but I can't add data to it. when I try the app crashes. I will update my app with that info. Also, I had no idea about the default thing.

Comment: If there's a crash, there's a stacktrace in logcat that's the key starting point for debugging.

Comment: So you want the name of the new table to be `Database1`?

Comment: @forpas in this example yes, and to fill it with some default values. Marc posted an answer that helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example [Delivery Droid Database Class](https://github.com/marchold/DeliveryDroid_v3/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/catglo/com/deliveryDatabase/DataBase.java)